# Uploading documents to a deal in hubspot

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-cms

I want to implement the following use case and I'm not sure how to do this with the Hubspot API and I don't find any solution within the documentation.

I created a custom request flow which is creating contacts and deals within Hubspot programmatically via the API in the next step the user should upload documents related to his case and I would like to upload and associate these documents with the related deal. Could someone help me or point me to the right spot in the documentation on how such a scenario can be established with the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following answer on the community board of Hubspot which worked for me:

> You can upload a File (and set the permissions) using the CMS Files
> API.
>
> Once you've upload the file you can the associate the file to your
> deal (using the File ID returned from the CMS Files API) with the
> Create Engagement API.
> Link: https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/Upload-File-to-a-contact/m-p/398156#M39358